# How to group rows in r based on row number

Tags: r, row, grouping

I would like to make 2 groups based on their row numbers (the 1st group being rows 2 to 47, and the 2nd group being rows 48 to 92). The groups are my top and bottom performing samples and I would like to compare the groups' values in the 12 data columns (genes being tested). So, my ultimate goal is to divide the samples into their appropriate groups, and run statistical analyses the group's values for each of the genes tested. Here is a small section of my table:

```
Sample    icaA   icaB   icaC   icaD
ST1       12     13     15     18
ST2       11     9      8      16
ST3       15     18     18     15
ST4       13     16     17     20
```

I don't know if I can use cbind to combine the groups.  I think I've also seen others flip the rows and columns; I can do that if needed.  I'm just a beginner with the software, so any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Can we got more information on the kind of statistical analysis you want?

Comment: T-test, std dev, mean

Comment: I definitely need more information on how exactly you'd like the output to be; it's not very clear at the moment (or it could just be me). So I took a shot in the dark and assumed what you wanted.

Comment: Table above does not have the actual data, just some examples of what it would look like to shorten it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first group:

```
df1 <- df[2:47, ]
```

To get the second group:

```
df2 <- df[48:92, ]
```

Right?

Then you can run stats on each column, for instance, like this:

```
apply(df1[-1], 2, mean)
```

...To get the mean for each column, in the first group.

Then for the mean of each column in the second group:

```
apply(df2[-1], 2, mean)
```

Then to bind each group into 1 dataframe (or matrix) again, then I recommend:

```
rbind(df1, df2)
```

Comment: The grouping worked, but the apply function just brings up NA values. `apply(Top25, 2, mean)` output:Samples icaA_ddCT icaB_ddCT icaC_ddCT icaD_ddCT fnbA_ddCT fnbB_ddCT clfA_ddCT 
       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 
clfB_ddCT  fib_ddCT ebps_ddCT  eno_ddCT  cna_ddCT 
       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA

Comment: Do you have NA values in your data? Also, are your variables a numeric or integer class, or are they in a character class? Check the former with `sum(is.na(Top25))` and the latter with `str(Top25)`

Comment: `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA  Samples icaA_ddCT icaB_ddCT icaC_ddCT icaD_ddCT fnbA_ddCT fnbB_ddCT clfA_ddCT 
       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 
clfB_ddCT  fib_ddCT ebps_ddCT  eno_ddCT  cna_ddCT` 
       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA

Comment: Yes, I do have NA values. I will check for both.  Thanks!

Comment: `sum(is.na(Top25))`  =0
`sum(is.na(Bottom25))` =13

Comment: `str(Top25)` = 'data.frame': 46 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Samples  : Factor w/ 91 levels "1479-SD5","1711-SA9",..: 6 7 11 13 14 15 18 19 20 21 ...
 $ icaA_ddCT: num  19.3 18.6 17.6 17.5 18 ...
 $ icaB_ddCT: num  17.3 18.9 17.1 16.6 17.7 ...
 $ icaC_ddCT: num  17.9 17.9 18.7 18.1 18.9 ...
 $ icaD_ddCT: num  18.3 19.2 17.6 16.8 17.5 ...
 $ fnbA_ddCT: num  22.3 17.1 17.3 16.3 17.1 ...
 $ fnbB_ddCT: num  23.8 14.7 15.4 14.3 15.1 ...
 $ clfA_ddCT: num  9.34 6.11 7.64 6.34 7.53 ...
 $ clfB_ddCT: num  0 10.8 10.08 8.98 9.53 ...
 $ fib_ddCT : num  24.9 15.3 14.9 12.9 13.8 ...

Comment: I was able to get a mean value for one of the columns using `TopMean <- mean(Top25$icaA_ddCt)` so I may just have to go through all of the columns individually.

Comment: Ok, so for `Top25`, try `apply(Top25[-1], 2, mean)`, which will ignore the first column, which is factor, and is why all columns were showing up as `NA`. Then `Bottom25` has `NA` values, so we can calculate the mean of those columns, by only including non-NA values in the mean calculation, with `apply(Bottom25[-1], 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`. And that should work. :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can, for example, do `library(dplyr); Top25 %>% summarise_all(mean)`.

Comment: I also went through and just did na.omit to the Bottom25 group, so that can clear those NAs for good.